# In Chromium browser but not in Firefox or Nautilus - Error opening directory '/media/tm/World': Permission denied

Tags: chromium

I get an error when trying to save browser pages to any partition other than Home when using Chromium.  The error does not occur in Firefox or Nautilus.

In an attempt to get write access to the Win 10 partition on my dual-boot system I may have changed some permissions before discovering that an upgrade in Windows had turned the troublesome fast boot back on.  Turning it off and installing ntfs-config helped get access to partitions for Firefox and Nautilus, but Chromium still gives the error message.

A similar issue was raised at:

[Cant acces files on my HDD to upload , download : '/media': Permission denied with Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017129/cant-acces-files-on-my-hdd-to-upload-download-media-permission-denied-wi)

where the solution was to reinstall.  Maybe someone can suggest a better solution!  Thanks!

Edit: Eventually this problem went away, probably due to an improvement through regular software updates. Chromium now allows saving on the various partitions of my system.

Comment: When you do `ps -fA`, is Chromium running as the same user as Firefox and Nautilus? Are there any AppArmor profiles active on Chromium that are logging denials in `/var/log/`?

Comment: That is NOT  a similar question. And are you sure it should be "tm" as a subdirectory?

Comment: @ Joseph
Sorry for the slow response - Inet has been very sporadic for the past few days.

Chromium and Firefox both show tm as the UID.

Searching the system log for Chromium and AppArmor showed a wealth of references, but none seemed to overlap.

Comment: @ Rinzwind  In what way is the question not similar?  In Update 2 the other user states that Firefox allows access to his ntfs system but Chromium does not.  
What should the directory be named?  In /media there is a file called ".created_by_python-fstab" that contains what appear to be mount points for the ntfs file systems:  
/media/Recovery,
/media/sda5,
/media/tm/OS,
/media/tm/World.
I wonder if updating Chromium alone will solve the problem.  Internet is slow now, so even that is a project.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098471/828768) worked for me.

Basically you need Ubuntu OS to allow Chromium to access system mounts and read/write partitions and removable storage.